# Center of mass of a composite body

Tags: mathematical-physics

Find the coordinates for the center of mass to the shaded out shape. How does one tackle these problems? I have tried a bunch of stuff... like considering the small halfcircle hole on the left under the x axis as negative area but I did not manage to come to the right answer.

where $X_i,A_i$ indicates the coordinates for the center of mass on the X-Axis and the area respectively.

$X_G = (A_1X_1+A_2X_2-A_3X_3)/(A_1+A_2-A_3)$

$A_1$ - > small halfcircle on the top right above the x axis

$A_2$ - > big halfcircle below the x axis

$A_3$ - > halfcircle on the bottom left below the x axis

Is this right?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how far you have proceeded. Have you divided the shaded figure into 3 more manageable figures? If you have, labeling them on your drawing would be helpful.

Comment: Wait, never mind. I think I have understood your divisions. Now let's see. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I read that I am supposed to consider the third small circle on the bottom left (under the X-axis) as negative mass. But when I do that I get zero for the coordinates of center of gravity for the x-axis (for the composite body)

Comment: Okay, then wait a second. Let me try and solve the question and see where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: Moreover, upon closer inspection, the formula you have written is wrong. It would be better if you calculate the center of mass of the shape below the x-axis first, rather than attempting to create a single formula.

Comment: I still get wrong

Comment: Check my post below. Remember that the area of the shape below is the area of the whole semi-circle minus the area of the small semicircle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the shape below the x-axis, let it be known as $A$
The coordinates of center of mass of this shape be $x$

Now consider a semi-circle that fills the hole. Let this shape be $A_1$ and its center of mass be $x_1$

Now consider the entire semi-circle below the x-axis ($A + A_1$). Let this be $A_2$
Let the center of mass of this be $x_2$

Thus, we have:
$$\frac{Ax + A_1x_1}{A + A_1} = x_2$$

Calculating the area of the shapes, and upon rearranging, you will get:
$$\frac{4x_2 - x_1}{3} = x$$

That was just a quick calculation, please feel free to correct.

Then find the center of mass of the semi-circle above the x-axis ($A_3,x_3$)

Let $X$ be the center of mass of composite body:
$$X = \frac{A_3x_3 + Ax}{A_3 + A}$$